# Spray: How to handle chunked response for both server and client api

Tags: scala, spray

I didn't find much useful info from the Spray document as well as the example code about chunk response handling.

Here's  my use case: (I believe it's a good candidate to add into spray's example for user who's interested in chunk response)

Basically, the architecture is like:

Browser  < -------------------- > Spray-can server  < ---------------- > Spray-can client Api < ---------------------------  > other RESTful service

Here're some feature requirements:

1. My Spray-can server will be used to serve some big static resource like pdf, images, etc. It's preferred to go with chunked response. Most of the resources are stored locally.
2. If no resource found locally at spray-can server, I'll try to use a spray-can client api to get one from some predefined RESTful service endpoint. The RESTful service could respond with normal http response or chunked response.
   My spray-can client api should be able to handle both cases and make the response directly pipe to -------- > spray-can server --------> browser. (maybe I can use a future to store the data locally at the same time, but that's another story)
3. for client api, the host-level one is good for me.

The Streamer actor in DemoService gives me some clue, but HostLevelApiDemo does not help much in my case.

Thanks in advance!

Leon

Comment: Seems like this question/answer covers most of the concerns: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827029/is-it-possible-to-install-a-callback-after-request-processing-is-finished-in-spr