# Scala Spray. Output text as file

Tags: scala, file, http, spray

I have some text data in DB and i want to output this data to user by file. How can i do this? Now i'm doing this way: 1. create tmp file. 2. write data to file. 3. Serve this file with getFromFile() spray's method.
Is it possible to do this without 1 and 2 steps?

Comment: You can do something similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827029/is-it-possible-to-install-a-callback-after-request-processing-is-finished-in-spr. Instead of creating a file just have a byte array and send back chunks. Maybe there is something simpler, but I'm not aware of it.

Comment: Thanks Alexsey bit it's too complicated, i hope there's is easier way. At least i know that i'm not the only one who don't like creating temporary files on HDD xD

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
respondWithMediaType("text/plain") {
      respondWithHeader(HttpHeaders.`Content-Disposition`.apply("attachment", Map("filename" -> ("text.txt")))) {
        implicit val bufferMarshaller = BasicMarshallers.byteArrayMarshaller("text/plain")
        autoChunk(ChunkSizeMagnet.fromChunkSize(5000000)) {
          withRangeSupport() {
            complete("file content".getBytes)
          }
        }
      }
    }
```